# Trying to call a generic version from a non-generic version using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, system.reflection

I'm trying to call the generic version using System.Reflection from the non-generic version.

When I run the migrations I'm getting the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1[[Domain.BalanceSnapshot, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTo
> ken=null]]' not found.

Why? How do I fix it?

```cs
public static void HasTenancy<TTenantKey>(
    this ModelBuilder modelBuilder,
    Type entityType,
    Expression<Func<TTenantKey>> tenantId,
    TenancyModelState<TTenantKey> tenancyModelState,
    string propertyName = null,
    bool? hasIndex = null,
    string indexNameFormat = null,
    NullTenantReferenceHandling? nullTenantReferenceHandling = null)
{
    var entityTypeBuilderType = typeof(EntityTypeBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
    var expressionTenantIdType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TTenantKey)));
    var tenancyModelStateType = typeof(TenancyModelState<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TTenantKey));

    var parameterTypes = new[]
    {
        entityTypeBuilderType,
        expressionTenantIdType,
        tenancyModelStateType,
        typeof(string),
        typeof(bool?),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(NullTenantReferenceHandling?)
    };

    var method = typeof(TenancyEFExtensions)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(HasTenancy))
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetParameters()
            .Select(p => p.ParameterType.IsGenericType ? p.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : p.ParameterType)
            .SequenceEqual(parameterTypes.Select(t => t.IsGenericType ? t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : t)))?.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, typeof(TTenantKey));

    method?.Invoke(null, new[]
    {
        Activator.CreateInstance(entityTypeBuilderType, entityType),
        tenantId,
        tenancyModelState,
        propertyName,
        hasIndex,
        indexNameFormat,
        nullTenantReferenceHandling
    });
}
```

```cs
public static void HasTenancy<TEntity, TTenantKey>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder,
    Expression<Func<TTenantKey>> tenantId,
    TenancyModelState<TTenantKey> tenancyModelState,
    string propertyName = null,
    bool? hasIndex = null,
    string indexNameFormat = null,
    NullTenantReferenceHandling? nullTenantReferenceHandling = null)
    where TEntity : class
{
    ArgCheck.NotNull(nameof(builder), builder);
    ArgCheck.NotNull(nameof(tenancyModelState), tenancyModelState);

    // get overrides or defaults
    var tenantKeyType = typeof(TTenantKey);
    propertyName ??= tenancyModelState.DefaultOptions.ReferenceName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
    hasIndex ??= tenancyModelState.DefaultOptions.IndexReferences;
    indexNameFormat ??= tenancyModelState.DefaultOptions.IndexNameFormat;
    nullTenantReferenceHandling ??= tenancyModelState.DefaultOptions.NullTenantReferenceHandling;
    tenancyModelState.Properties[typeof(TEntity)] = new()
    {
        ReferenceName = propertyName,
        IndexReferences = hasIndex.Value,
        IndexNameFormat = indexNameFormat,
        NullTenantReferenceHandling = nullTenantReferenceHandling.Value
    };

    // add property
    var property = builder.Property(tenantKeyType, propertyName);

    // is required / not null
    if (nullTenantReferenceHandling == NullTenantReferenceHandling.NotNullDenyAccess ||
        nullTenantReferenceHandling == NullTenantReferenceHandling.NotNullGlobalAccess)
    {
        property.IsRequired();
    }

    // add index
    if (hasIndex.Value)
    {
        var index = builder.HasIndex(propertyName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(indexNameFormat))
        {
            index.HasName(string.Format(indexNameFormat, propertyName));
        }
    }

    // add tenant query filter

    // Entity e
    var entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
    // "TenantId"
    var propertyNameConstant = Expression.Constant(propertyName, typeof(string));
    // EF.Property<long>
    var efPropertyMethod = ((MethodCallExpression)((Expression<Func<object, string, TTenantKey>>)((e, p) => EF.Property<TTenantKey>(e, p))).Body).Method;
    // EF.Property<long>(e, "TenantId")
    var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(efPropertyMethod, entityParameter, propertyNameConstant);
    // _tenancyContext.Tenant.Id == EF.Property<long>(e, "TenantId")
    var tenantCondition = Expression.Equal(tenantId.Body, efPropertyCall);

    if (nullTenantReferenceHandling == NullTenantReferenceHandling.NotNullDenyAccess ||
        nullTenantReferenceHandling == NullTenantReferenceHandling.NotNullGlobalAccess)
    {
        var nullableTenantKeyType = tenantKeyType.IsValueType ? typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(tenantKeyType) : tenantKeyType;
        var nullableTenantKey = tenantKeyType.IsValueType ? Expression.Convert(tenantId.Body, nullableTenantKeyType) : tenantId.Body;
        var nullTenantKey = Expression.Constant(null, nullableTenantKeyType);
        if (nullTenantReferenceHandling == NullTenantReferenceHandling.NotNullDenyAccess)
        {
            // (long?)_tenancyContext.Tenant.Id != (long?)null && _tenancyContext.Tenant.Id == EF.Property<long>(e, "TenantId")
            tenantCondition = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.NotEqual(nullableTenantKey, nullTenantKey), tenantCondition);
        }
        else if (nullTenantReferenceHandling == NullTenantReferenceHandling.NotNullGlobalAccess)
        {
            // (long?)_tenancyContext.Tenant.Id == (long?)null || _tenancyContext.Tenant.Id == EF.Property<long>(e, "TenantId")
            tenantCondition = Expression.OrElse(Expression.Equal(nullableTenantKey, nullTenantKey), tenantCondition);
        }
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(tenantCondition, entityParameter);
    builder.HasQueryFilter(lambda);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating instance of `EntityTypeBuilder<>` looks a bit strange to me (note that it has [single ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.-ctor?view=efcore-7.0) that accepts instance of `IMutableEntityType`, not `Type`):

```cs
var entityTypeBuilderType = typeof(EntityTypeBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
// ....
Activator.CreateInstance(entityTypeBuilderType, entityType);
```

Since you are passing `ModelBuilder` you can try using non-generic version of `Entity` method - `modelBuilder.Entity(entityType)` (with corresponding changes to code) or try finding the generic one and invoking it (i.e. simulating the `modelBuilder.Entity<...>` call):

```
var methodInfo = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethod(
    nameof(ModelBuilder.Entity), 
    genericParameterCount: 1, 
    types: Type.EmptyTypes);
var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(entityType));
var entityBuilder = genericMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, null); // instead of Activator.CreateInstance
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. :) It's also strange that I have to compare `entityTypeBuilderType`, `expressionTenantIdType`, `tenancyModelStateType` but in fact I'm not comparing them because of the `ParameterType.IsGenericType ? p.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : p.ParameterType` check.

Comment: @nop Was glad to help! TBH have not gone through the methods thoroughly, so can't tell =)